# Is .Net 4.5 included in Windows update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, .net-4.5

I know that .net 4.0 is included in Windows 7s SP1. But if you keep your computer updated via Windows update, will .net 4.5 be installed?

Comment: .NET 4.5.1 is indeed pushed over Windows Update.

Comment: But is it pushed to people who have .net 4.0 or only to users who have 4.5?

Comment: .net 4.0 is **NOT** included in Windows 7 Sp1

Comment: @Ziv - Check?  You can also download it [manually](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779).  If your application requires a specific version of .NET Framework its always best to supply the installer to the user.